# Count cumulative total in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am using `count` and `group by` to get the number of subscribers registered each day:

```
  SELECT created_at, COUNT(email)  
    FROM subscriptions 
GROUP BY created at;
```

Result:

```
created_at  count
-----------------
04-04-2011  100
05-04-2011   50
06-04-2011   50
07-04-2011  300
```

I want to get the cumulative total of subscribers every day instead. How do I get this?

```
created_at  count
-----------------
04-04-2011  100
05-04-2011  150
06-04-2011  200
07-04-2011  500
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

With larger datasets, [**window functions**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) are the most efficient way to perform these kinds of queries -- the table will be scanned only once, instead of once for each date, like a self-join would do. It also looks a lot simpler. :) PostgreSQL 8.4 and up have support for window functions.

This is what it looks like:

```
SELECT created_at, sum(count(email)) OVER (ORDER BY created_at)
FROM subscriptions
GROUP BY created_at;
```

Here `OVER` creates the window; `ORDER BY created_at` means that it has to sum up the counts in `created_at` order.

---

**Edit:** If you want to remove duplicate emails within a single day, you can use `sum(count(distinct email))`. Unfortunately this won't remove duplicates that cross different dates.

If you want to remove *all* duplicates, I think the easiest is to use a subquery and `DISTINCT ON`. This will attribute emails to their earliest date (because I'm sorting by created_at in ascending order, it'll choose the earliest one):

```
SELECT created_at, sum(count(email)) OVER (ORDER BY created_at)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (email) created_at, email
    FROM subscriptions ORDER BY email, created_at
) AS subq
GROUP BY created_at;
```

If you create an index on `(email, created_at)`, this query shouldn't be too slow either.

---

(If you want to test, this is how I created the sample dataset)

```
create table subscriptions as
   select date '2000-04-04' + (i/10000)::int as created_at,
          'foofoobar@foobar.com' || (i%700000)::text as email
   from generate_series(1,1000000) i;
create index on subscriptions (email, created_at);
```

Comment: This is great intgr, only that my subscriptions table contains a lot of duplicate email rows. So what `over` is doing is `sum`-ming the `count` numbers, but I still need to recalculate the unique emails on every subsequent date.

Comment: I updated my answer with a `DISTINCT ON` subquery. It's still a lot faster than Andriy's answer -- can process a million rows within a few seconds -- but perhaps more complicated.

Comment: Nice tip on the generate_series function!

Comment: Note that `DISTINCT ON` can also be turned into an equivalent query with `GROUP BY`; in this case, `SELECT email, MIN(created_at) as created_at FROM subscriptions GROUP BY email`. Which is more efficient will probably vary, although ready-sorted sub-query from the `DISTINCT ON` seems to give some advantage to the sort needed by the Window function.

Comment: I'd like to have this on a per month basis, how would I need to change this query? I'm having real problems with that.

Comment: To anyone reading this answer, see the answer that uses `rollup` posted by @Pstr.  In 2021+ `rollup` seems to be the way to go (more performant).

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
SELECT a.created_at,
       (SELECT COUNT(b.email)
          FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS b
         WHERE b.created_at <= a.created_at) AS count
  FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS a
```

Answer (score 5):

To anyone seeing this answer today (2021)
You can use rollup

```
SELECT created_at, COUNT(email)  
    FROM subscriptions 
GROUP BY rollup(created_at);
```

this will give you a new row with the total

```
created_at  count
-----------------
04-04-2011  100
05-04-2011   50
06-04-2011   50
07-04-2011  300
NULL        500
```

You can also use rollup for partial results if you have more than one parameter to show in your group by. If you have a `created_by` for instance:

```
SELECT created_at, created_by COUNT(email)  
    FROM subscriptions 
GROUP BY rollup(created_at, created_by);
```

this will give you a new row with the total

```
created_at  created_by  count
-----------------------------
04-04-2011     1        80
04-04-2011     2        20
04-04-2021    NULL      100
05-04-2011     1        20
05-04-2011     2        30
05-04-2011    NULL      50
NULL          NULL      150
```

I only took the numbers of the first two days, but that's the idea. it will show grouped by date, then total of that day, then the total of totals.

Order matters in the `rollup()` here, as to how the partial totals will be displayed

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer in 2021+ !
On my system:  Window function (Planning Time: 1.134 ms,  Execution Time: 1.045 ms) , Rollup (Planning Time: 0.245 ms,Execution Time: 0.642 ms). Rollup is significantly more performant.

Comment: This isn't cumulative, as the OP requests.

Comment: rollup doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  s1.created_at,
  COUNT(s2.email) AS cumul_count
FROM subscriptions s1
  INNER JOIN subscriptions s2 ON s1.created_at >= s2.created_at
GROUP BY s1.created_at
```

Comment: I've tried the `sum(s2.count)` and the console gives an error: 'aggregate function calls cannot be nested'

Comment: I meant that to be `COUNT(s2.email)`, sorry. Please see my edited solution.

Comment: Thanks buddy! I was working with a more complicated query, and your structure is easy to understand (and thus, to implement).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want only one row per day and you want to still show days without any subscriptions (suppose nobody subscribes for a certain date, do you want to show that date with the balance of the previous day?). If this is the case, you can use the 'with' feature:

```
with recursive serialdates(adate) as (
    select cast('2011-04-04' as date)
    union all
    select adate + 1 from serialdates where adate < cast('2011-04-07' as date)
)
select D.adate,
(
    select count(distinct email)
    from subscriptions
    where created_at between date_trunc('month', D.adate) and D.adate
)
from serialdates D
```

Comment: Thanks, that `with` function could be useful too. Learnt something new.

Comment: Instead of serialdates you can use the built-in function: `generate_series(timestamp '2011-04-04', timestamp '2011-04-07', interval '1 day')`

Answer (score -3):

The best way is to have a calendar table:
calendar (
  date date,
  month int,
  quarter int,
  half int,
  week int,
  year int
)

Then, you can join this table to make summary for the field you need.

Comment: That has nothing to do with getting a running total.