# Calculating Cumulative Sum in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, analytic-functions, cumulative-sum

I want to find the cumulative or running amount of field and insert it from staging to table. My staging structure is something like this:

```
ea_month    id       amount    ea_year    circle_id
April       92570    1000      2014        1
April       92571    3000      2014        2
April       92572    2000      2014        3
March       92573    3000      2014        1
March       92574    2500      2014        2
March       92575    3750      2014        3
February    92576    2000      2014        1
February    92577    2500      2014        2
February    92578    1450      2014        3
```

I want my target table to look something like this:

```
ea_month    id       amount    ea_year    circle_id    cum_amt
February    92576    1000      2014        1           1000 
March       92573    3000      2014        1           4000
April       92570    2000      2014        1           6000
February    92577    3000      2014        2           3000
March       92574    2500      2014        2           5500
April       92571    3750      2014        2           9250
February    92578    2000      2014        3           2000
March       92575    2500      2014        3           4500
April       92572    1450      2014        3           5950
```

I am really very much confused with how to go about achieving this result. I want to achieve this result using PostgreSQL.

Can anyone suggest how to go about achieving this result-set?

Comment: How do you get the cum_amount of 1000 in your target table? For circle_id, the amount seems to be 2000.

Comment: @user1724295 He is grouping by `ea_year`, `circle_id`, `ea_month`. Then want to take `cum_amt`

Comment: I think that amount column in target table are wrong and cum_amt of course too. E.g. id 92576 has amount 2000 not 1000. If I'm right please edit this - it is confusing

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Basically, you need a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html). That's a standard feature nowadays. In addition to genuine window functions, you can use *any* aggregate function as window function in Postgres by appending an `OVER` clause.

The special difficulty here is to get partitions and sort order right:

```sql
SELECT ea_month, id, amount, ea_year, circle_id
     , sum(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY circle_id
                         ORDER BY ea_year, ea_month) AS cum_amt
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY circle_id, ea_year, ea_month;
```

And *no* `GROUP BY`.

The sum for each row is calculated from the first row in the partition to the current row - or quoting [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) to be precise:

> The default framing option is `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, which is
> the same as `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. With
> `ORDER BY`, this sets the frame to be **all rows from the partition
> start up through the current row's last `ORDER BY` peer**.

Bold emphasis mine.
This is the cumulative (or "running") sum you are after.

In default `RANGE` mode, rows with the same rank in the sort order are *"peers"* - same `(circle_id, ea_year, ea_month)` in this query. All of those show the same running sum with all peers added to the sum. But I assume your table is `UNIQUE` on `(circle_id, ea_year, ea_month)`, then the sort order is deterministic and no row has peers. (And you might as well use the cheaper `ROWS` mode.)

Postgres 11 added tools to include / exclude peers with the new [`frame_exclusion` options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS). See:

- [Aggregating all values not in the same group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67975901/aggregating-all-values-not-in-the-same-group/67979056#67979056)

Now, `ORDER BY ... ea_month` ***won't work with strings for month names***. Postgres would sort alphabetically according to the locale setting.

If you have actual `date` values stored in your table you can sort properly. If not, I suggest to replace `ea_year` and `ea_month` with a single column `the_date` of type [`date`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) in your table.

- Transform what you have with [`to_date()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html):

  ```
    to_date(ea_year || ea_month , 'YYYYMonth') AS the_date
  ```
- For display, you can get original strings with [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html):

  ```
    to_char(the_date, 'Month') AS ea_month
    to_char(the_date, 'YYYY')  AS ea_year
  ```

While stuck with the unfortunate design, this will work:

```
SELECT ea_month, id, amount, ea_year, circle_id
     , sum(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY circle_id ORDER BY the_date) AS cum_amt
FROM   (SELECT *, to_date(ea_year || ea_month, 'YYYYMonth') AS the_date FROM tbl) sub
ORDER  BY circle_id, mon;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. Can you help me with one more thing. I want to implement the same thing using a cursor with the logic being every circle will have just one record for a month of a year. And the function is supposed to run once every month. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @YousufSultan: Most of the time there is a better solution than a cursor. That's definitely stuff for a new question. Please start a new question.

Comment: I find this answer incomplete without at least a note that there is "framing" going on here which defaults to `range unbounded preceding`, which is the same as `range between unbounded preceding and current row`. This is why `sum()`when used as a window function produces a running total -- while other window functions don't have this default frame.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: I added some more above to clarify.

Comment: Here's a link to a similar question with a simpler query (the `PARTITION` is not always needed to create a running total): https://stackoverflow.com/a/5700744/175830

Comment: Maybe `ORDER  BY circle_id, month;` should be `ORDER  BY circle_id, ea_year, ea_month;`?

Comment: @Ciro Oh yes, thanks - matching the original table schema.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter  I think the last query is wrong. `ORDER  BY circle_id, the_date`. Should also have a alias....

Comment: @jian Indeed, an alias for the subquery was missing, thanks!

Comment: thanks for the pg reference link . Mysql doc dosen't say anything for order by inside windows function will impact the sum.

Comment: This answer is SO HELPFUL!!!!