# Conditional sum on columns in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Subway data
Columns:

1. Station_id (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3)
2. Number of people boarded
3. Number of people deboarded
4. Occupancy

Occupancy at current station = Number of people already in the train at previous station + Number of people boarded - Number of people deboarded

I am trying to fill the occupancy column. The issue is that the dataset is for multiple subway trains so station_id changes back to 1 and on that station number of people deboarded is always 0 since it is the station from which train journey begins. I have got no clue on how to do this in postgresql. The occupancy column in the sample image below is empty and needs to be filled

The train journeys are sorted and grouped.
[image]

Comment: sample data and the expected output would really be helpful.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) in tabular format and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Do you have `train_id` you can add to your data set?  Do you have timestamps?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have uploaded a sample data. There is no timestamp column but I created an id column which is a serial

Comment: SQL tables and their IDs aren't really meant to be used like this. But you should be able to do this using a "running total".  Maybe this thread would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841206/calculating-cumulative-sum-in-postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the difference of the cumulative sums.  The trick is identifying the groups, which I'll do by counting the number of times that `station_id` has been `1` up to that record.

```
select s.*,
       (sum(boarded) over (partition by grp order by id) -
        sum(deboarded) over (partition by grp order by id)
       ) as occupants
from (select s.*,
             count(*) filter (where station_id = 1) over (order by id) as grp
      from subwaydata s
     ) s;
```