# Rails: Group and sum while adding last values (Fibonacci)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to group quotes sum per month, while adding last sums.

For example:

```
Jan: 300€
Fev: 200€
Mars: 100€
```

What the group should return is:

```
Jan:300€
Fev: 500€ (200 + Jan's 300)
Mars: 600€ (100 + Fev's 500)
```

Current SQL:

```
current_user.quotes.group_by_month(:created_at, last: 12).sum(:price)
```

I'm using the `groupdate` gem.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a pure sql/activerecord solution? Or are you OK with a ruby one?

Comment: @thesecretmaster I prefer SQL, but a ruby solution is helpful too. Thank you.

Comment: @Yassine Would you mind if using postgresql's solution.

Comment: @D-Shih No problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If used `postgresql` you can use *windows function*

1. `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` first row,`CURRENT ROW` current rows
2. use `sum` function to Accumulate

like this.

```
select name,sum(price) 
         over(order by (select 1) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)  "price"
from T
```

*sqlfidde:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/763e3/7*

[Widows function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS)

Answer (score 1):

Solution in Ruby:

```
s = 0
current_user.quotes.group_by_month(:created_at, last: 12).
  sum(:price).
  transform_values.map { |v| s += v }
```

as there is only a hash of 12 elements, i suggest the performance penalty of using ruby instead of sql are marginal. Using SQL would be much harder and not possible only with simple ActiveRecord Arel methods or probably database specific, see e.g. [Calculating Cumulative Sum in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841206/calculating-cumulative-sum-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 1):

We can use the following code for that

```
 quotes = current_user.quotes
 sum = 0
 quotes.each_with_object({}) do |quote,hassh|
     hassh[quote.name] = sum = quote.price + sum
 end
 hassh
```