# Postgresql: Calculate monthly running total with some months missing

Tags: sql, postgresql, cumulative-sum

### I have a table like this:

```
| acct| month | total |
-------------------------------
| 123 | 02    | 100
| 123 | 03    | 100
| 123 | 04    | 100
| 123 | 06    | 100
| 123 | 07    | 100
```

I want to get a running total grouped by acct for each month. However as shown above the table does not have a record for month 5 (basically nothing changed in month 5), but I still want to create a row for month 5 that will be the same as the previous month 4 so that the result looks like:

---

```
| acct| month | total |
-------------------------------
| 123 | 02    | 100
| 123 | 03    | 200
| 123 | 04    | 300
| 123 | 05    | 300
| 123 | 06    | 400
| 123 | 07    | 500
```

Is there anyway to do this in Postgresql? I've explored using over and partition as described here [Calculating Cumulative Sum in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841206/calculating-cumulative-sum-in-postgresql) but that is for the case where all months are present.

Comment: How does this add up to 600?  There is only 500 in the original table.

Comment: woops, that's fixed now

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you really want a cumulative sum with missing months, use `generate_series()` to generate the dates and then `left join` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.acct, gs.mon, sum(total) over (order by mon)
from generate_series(2, 7, 1) gs(mon) left join
     t
     on gs.mon = t.mon;
```