# How to write Window functions using Druid?

Tags: sql, window-functions, druid

For example, i wanted to write Window functions like `sum over (window)`

Since over clause is not supported by Druid, how do i achieve the same using Druid Native query API or SQL API?

Comment: There is an extension called ["moving-average-query"](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-contrib/moving-average-query.html#basic-example), I dont know whether it works for your need.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a GroupBy Query. As Druid is a time series database, you have to specify your interval (window) where you want to query data from. You can use aggregation methods over this data, for example a SUM() aggregation.

If you want, you can also do extra filtering within your aggregation, like "only sum records where city=paris"). You could also apply the SUM aggregation only to records which exists in a certain time window within your selected interval.

If you are a PHP user then maybe this package is handy for you: https://github.com/level23/druid-client#sum 
We have tried to implement an easy way to query such data.

Comment: This is not really an answer, the questioner is asking if one can some something like:
select ... `sum(value) OVER (PARTITION BY some_dim ORDER BY date_month) AS cumulative_total_value ` like this question is asking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22843199/3089084