# How do I maintain a running/rollover balance in Clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

Say I've a table of Date, Val.
Now, I want to maintain a rolling balance where Val gets added to the previous row to give X, which then gets added to the next row and thus it continues to give rise to a column that has the rolling balance.
So on any date I query, I can get the current balance.

Using window functions, I can always add the current row with the previous row, but I'm not able to figure how to carry over that value to the next row's summation.

Answer (score 0):

Window functions does the job you asked.  Please look for "order by" clause of WF:

```sql
select sum(Val) over (order by Date)
```

sliding window from unbound preceding to current row is default for order by, to make a task of cumulative summing easy.

See expanded answer here - [Calculating Cumulative Sum in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841206/calculating-cumulative-sum-in-postgresql)