# Sum of cummulative difference within group in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like the one below. I will like to find the sum of the cumulative difference between the target value daily actual value.

```
ID  | Date    | Target_value | Daily_Value
1   |01/10/20 |   200        |   5
2   |01/10/20 |   500        |   2
3   |05/10/20 |   600        |   10
1   |04/11/20 |   200        |   50
2   |05/11/20 |   500        |   80
3   |05/11/20 |   600        |   40
1   |06/12/20 |   200        |   50
4   |06/12/20 |   400        |   30
5   |07/12/20 |   300        |   20

Expected output

Date     | Target_value - monthly_cummulative daily_value          |
   10/20 | (200 + 500 + 600) - (5 + 2 + 10) =   1283               |
   11/20 | (200 + 500 + 600) - (17 + 50 + 80 + 40) = 1113          |
   12/20 | (200 + 500 + 600 + 400 + 300) - (17 + 170 + 100) = 1713 |
```

This is similar to this [Calculating Cumulative Sum in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841206/calculating-cumulative-sum-in-postgresql) but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in two steps.  First, aggregate by year and month and generate the sums for the target and daily values.  Then, use `SUM()` as an analytic function with a rolling window across the entire intermediate table to generate the difference.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', Date), SUM(Target_value) AS Target_value,
           SUM(Daily_Value) AS Daily_Value
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY 1
)

SELECT ym, Target_value,
       Target_Value - SUM(Daily_Value) OVER (ORDER BY ym) AS output
FROM cte
ORDER BY ym;
```

[image: screenshot from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Cool.  Hadn't used date_trunc before.

Comment: `DATE_TRUNC('month', Date),` in the CTE needs to be `DATE_TRUNC('month', Date) ym,`  like how you handled the cumulative sum.

Answer (score 0):

Group by the truncated dates.

Then Sum over the daily sum.

But the targets need to be handled seperatly.

> ```
> WITH CTE_TARGETS AS (
>   SELECT ID
>   , MAX(Target_Value) AS Target_Value
>   , MIN(DATE_TRUNC('month', Date)) as month_first
>   FROM your_table
>   GROUP BY ID
> ), CTE_MONTHLY AS
> (
>   SELECT 
>     DATE_TRUNC('month', Date) AS month_first
>   , SUM(SUM(Daily_Value)) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('month', Date)) AS month_daily
>   FROM your_table t
>   GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('month', Date)
> ) 
> SELECT 
>   TO_CHAR(mon.month_first, 'MM/YY') AS Month
> , SUM(Target_Value) - month_daily AS monthly_cummulative
> FROM CTE_MONTHLY mon
> JOIN CTE_TARGETS tgt ON tgt.month_first <= mon.month_first
> GROUP BY mon.month_first, month_daily
> ORDER BY mon.month_first
> ```

| month | monthly_cummulative |
| --- | --- |
| 10/20 | 1283 |
| 11/20 | 1113 |
| 12/20 | 1713 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=358d2ca7d1b4e9bac0a7feac0f3d27e1)*

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oops, you are correct sir. Thx for pointing it out. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Postgres, AWS Redshift requires a frame clause when using `"over (order by ...)"`.

The following is the updated version of LukStorms' answer.

```
SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', date), 'MM/YY') AS MonthYear
, SUM(Target_value) 
  - SUM(SUM(Daily_Value)) OVER (ORDER BY MonthYear ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS monthly_cumulative
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY MonthYear
ORDER BY MonthYear;
```

The frame clause added here is `"ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW"`.

For conciseness, I have also replaced all but the first use of `DATE_TRUNC` by the alias `MonthYear`.