# Cumulative Sum with Postgre SQL using date truncating

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm relatively new to using SQL in Apache Superset and I'm not sure where to look or how to solve my problem.

The short version of what I am trying to do is add a column of cumulative sum based on the total number of users by month.

Here is my PostgreSQL query so far:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(DATE_TRUNC('month', crdate)) AS "Month", 
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS "COUNT_DISTINCT(user_id)"
FROM 
    datasource 
WHERE 
    user_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  
    DATE(DATE_TRUNC('month', create))
ORDER BY 
    "COUNT_DISTINCT(user_id)" DESC
```

[Sum of Users by Month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo5sT.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841206/calculating-cumulative-sum-in-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors, you can't order by an alias and in group by your date column is wrong, so it should be like this:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(DATE_TRUNC('month', crdate)) AS "Month", 
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS "COUNT_DISTINCT(user_id)"
FROM 
    datasource 
WHERE 
    user_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  
    DATE(DATE_TRUNC('month', crdate)) AS "Month"
ORDER BY 
    COUNT_DISTINCT(user_id) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your query a Basis for the Window function

> ```
> CREATE TABLE datasource(crdate timestamp,user_id int)
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (
> SELECT
>      DATE_TRUNC('month',"crdate") as "Month",
>     COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS "COUNT_DISTINCT(user_id)"
> FROM 
>     datasource 
> WHERE 
>     user_id IS NOT NULL
> GROUP BY  
>     DATE_TRUNC('month', "crdate")
> )
> SELECT "Month", SUM("COUNT_DISTINCT(user_id)") OVER (ORDER BY "Month") as cumultatove_sum
> FROM CTE
> ```

> ```
> Month | cumultatove_sum
> :---- | --------------:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=93fd32bea0ecc791f660f8764a25229d)*