# Cumulative Totals By Date in Postgres Using Window Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I'm looking to produce a simple cumulative total by date in SQL, but running into a seemingly-simple issue.  I have developed a work around, but imagine there's a way to do what I want without the extra step.  Basically what I'm looking for is:

`|    Date    | Count |
| 2015-01-01 |   1   |
| 2015-01-02 |   5   |
| 2015-01-03 |   8   |
| 2015-01-04 |   9   |
| 2015-01-05 |   9   |`

We can assume that the table has only two rows - `id` and `date` - and what I would like to see is exactly what is above; however, when I run the following code, I get repeated rows:

`SELECT date, count(*) over (order by date) AS cumulative_count FROM my_table;`

Returns:

`|    Date    | Count |
| 2015-01-01 |   1   |
| 2015-01-02 |   5   |
| 2015-01-02 |   5   |
| 2015-01-02 |   5   |
| 2015-01-02 |   5   |
| 2015-01-02 |   5   |
| 2015-01-03 |   8   |
| 2015-01-03 |   8   |
...etc.`

My workaround solution has been to use `SELECT DISTINCT date, count(*) over (order by date) AS cumulative_count FROM my_table;` but I'd imagine there's a better way that I'm just missing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with being `DISTINCT` here. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698452/count-cumulative-total-in-postgresql

Comment: Why use a window function at all in this case?

Comment: Is there a more simple way to get cumulative/running totals without using a window function?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use distinct you could use a GROUP BY DATE, COUNT

Comment: `group by` would not compute a cumulative total but a total `by date` unless you do it in a subquery and then do the cummulative total in the outer query. But that is more trouble than just use `distinct`