# Cumulative (running) sum with django orm and postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

Is it possible to calculate the cumulative (running) sum using django's orm? Consider the following model:

```
class AModel(models.Model):
    a_number = models.IntegerField()
```

with a set of data where `a_number = 1`. Such that I have a number ( >1 ) of `AModel` instances in the database all with `a_number=1`. I'd like to be able to return the following:

```
AModel.objects.annotate(cumsum=??).values('id', 'cumsum').order_by('id')
>>> ({id: 1, cumsum: 1}, {id: 2, cumsum: 2}, ... {id: N, cumsum: N})
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to limit/filter the cumulative sum. So in the above case I'd like to limit the result to `cumsum <= 2`

I believe that in postgresql one can achieve a cumulative sum using window functions. How is this translated to the ORM?

Comment: I don't get it. What is cumsum? And there's only one record with id=1

Comment: cumsum == cumulative sum, obviously this is for more than one record - edited to make clearer so the size of the set of data is greater than one.

Comment: I don't think you cand do it with the ORM...use python instead

Comment: The phrase you are looking for is the [running total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total) (or running sum). Which is a specialized case of [moving aggregates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xaggr.html#XAGGR-MOVING-AGGREGATES). Which are a kind of [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html).

Comment: I think cumulative sum and running total are the same thing http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CumulativeSum.html . But yes it is a window function I'm after.

Comment: @wrdeman yes, you may be right, but the term *cumulative sum* is rarely used (I mainly found MATLAB references and this worfram). I'm not a native english speaker though, but I've heard of "running sum" before, a lot.

Comment: it's usage may be more field specific (e.g. physics/statistics where it is not that uncommon) but thanks for pointing this out and I've amended the title to reflect this alternative usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Dima Kudosh's answer and based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/5700744/2240489 I had to do the following:
I removed the reference to `PARTITION BY` in the sql and replaced with `ORDER BY` resulting in.

```
AModel.objects.annotate(
    cumsum=Func(
        Sum('a_number'), 
        template='%(expressions)s OVER (ORDER BY %(order_by)s)', 
        order_by="id"
    ) 
).values('id', 'cumsum').order_by('id', 'cumsum')
```

This gives the following sql:

```
SELECT "amodel"."id",
SUM("amodel"."a_number") 
OVER (ORDER BY id) AS "cumsum" 
FROM "amodel" 
GROUP BY "amodel"."id" 
ORDER BY "amodel"."id" ASC, "cumsum" ASC
```

Dima Kudosh's answer was not summing the results but the above does.

Answer (score 16):

For reference, starting with Django 2.0 it is possible to use the [`Window`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) function to achieve this result:

```
AModel.objects.annotate(cumsum=Window(Sum('a_number'), order_by=F('id').asc()))\
              .values('id', 'cumsum').order_by('id', 'cumsum')
```

Comment: Interesting to know also, the window functions do not work with SqLite3.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, I found this to be a good solution for me. I didn't need the result to be a QuerySet, so I could afford to do this, since I was just going to plot the data using D3.js:

```
import numpy as np
import datettime

today = datetime.datetime.date()

raw_data = MyModel.objects.filter('date'=today).values_list('a_number', flat=True)

cumsum = np.cumsum(raw_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this with [Func expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions).

```
from django.db.models import Func, Sum

AModel.objects.annotate(cumsum=Func(Sum('a_number'), template='%(expressions)s OVER (PARTITION BY %(partition_by)s)', partition_by='id')).values('id', 'cumsum').order_by('id')
```

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your answer. It didn't quite work for me and I've posted my amendment.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
AModel.objects.order_by("id").extra(select={"cumsum":'SELECT SUM(m.a_number) FROM table_name m WHERE m.id <= table_name.id'}).values('id', 'cumsum')
```

where `table_name` should be the name of table in database.