# Django ORM QUERY Adjacent row sum with sqlite

Tags: django, sqlite

In my database I'm storing data as below:

```
id    amt
--  ------- 
1    100 
2    -50  
3    100 
4   -100 
5    200
```

I want to get output like below

```
id   amt  balance
-- ----- -------
1    100   100
2    -50    50
3    100   150
4   -100    50
5    200   250
```

How to do with in django orm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cumulative (running) sum with django orm and postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517901/cumulative-running-sum-with-django-orm-and-postgresql)

Comment: does not work with sqlite

Comment: In plain sql, you'd use `sum()` as a window function: `SELECT id, amt, sum(amt) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS balance FROM yourtable` (At least in modern versions of sqlite). Dunno about with an ORM, though.

Comment: You can try to use @Shawn answer in pair with `Model.objects.raw("some_sql")`