# Grafana Panel with entity count + history

Tags: sql, postgresql, grafana

I would like to create a Grafana panel with our user database (PostgreSQL). This scene from HBO's Silicon Valley already describes it perfectly.

[image]

But I can't figure out how to get the "historical count" working.

My rough idea is this:

```
SELECT
    created as time,
    count(*)
FROM
    user
WHERE 
    created BETWEEN "FIXED START DATE" AND created
ORDER BY 
    created
ASC
```

But I encounter issues, that I have to add a GROUP BY clause, because of the aggregate function. Which seems legitimate. But how can I do an aggregation with the "history" of existing entities to the time of the graph position?

I would be thankful for every assistant advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a nice solution which works pretty good with Grafana.

The correct term to look for was (count cumulative total) and it uses a *window function*. (see here: [Count cumulative total in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698452/count-cumulative-total-in-postgresql/5700744#5700744))

```
SELECT $__time(created), sum(count(*)) OVER (ORDER BY created) as "Benutzeranzahl"
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (email) created, email
    FROM user  ORDER BY email, created
) AS subq
GROUP BY created;
```

The result looks perfect!

[image: Grafana Count cumulative total]

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted. Thank you! But this seems to be very slow.